# Show all not null data in specific tablename in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Good day, i want to show all the transferees student only in my database.. i am using this query but it is not working.. Can someone help me with this.. Thank you in advance

```
Select s1.SID, s1.Lastname, s1.Firstname, s1.MI, g1.Course, s1.PreviousSchool, s1.DOT, s1.SContact, s1.SAdd,
COUNT(g1.Course) As `Number Of Passed Subject`, 
SUM(su.LecUnit) As `Total Of Units Passed` 
From student s1 
INNER Join grades g1 ON s1.SID = g1.StudentID 
INNER Join subjects su ON su.SubjectCode = g1.SubjectCode 
WHERE 
(s1.DOT IS NOT NULL 
AND 
s1.PreviousSchool IS NOT NULL 
AND 
s1.SContact IS NOT NULL 
AND 
s1.SAdd IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: *it is not working* - this tells about nothing. Error? provide complete error message. Something else? provide detailed description.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is not complete. In ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL Mode the query will fail. Add all non-aggregated columns included into the output list ibto GROUP BY expression.

Comment: There is no error message.. but when i run this query even the students that is not transferees is still there...

Comment: Provide a fiddle or (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) with sample data, and show desired output for this data.

Comment: Your output list contains 9 non-aggregated and 2 aggregated output columns whereas in GROUP BY expression only one of these non-aggregated columns is used.

Comment: Remove the count,sum group by and order by - still nothing? Then no data which matches criteria.